# How can I spot vehicles when flying a jet?

Tags: pc, battlefield-3

For some reason I can't seem to be able to spot other vehicles when flying a jet. I've assigned the "spot / communications" key to a joystick button, keep flying directly at vehicles and hit that button, but nothing happens. If I keep the button pressed, I see the com menu, so it must be assigned correctly.

I should probably also note that I am playing in Hardcore mode.

Is this a known limitation (perhaps with the new BF3 patch or on Hardcore servers only), or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: Given that I've never been able to fly a jet successfully for more than 10 seconds, I'm not going to post an answer, but two ideas: 1. In Hardcore mode spotting anything will only cause the icon to show up on your minimap, not on the main screen. 2. Generally when flying a jet I was under the impression that you should be relying on your team-mates to do the spotting for you.

Comment: Actually, regardless of any other information, if you reassign spot/communications, it won't work any more, or more appropriately, it won't work on your new button, but will continue to work on the default location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr Smooth's comment above lead me on the right path: This is indeed a bug. If you reassign spot/communications, it won't work any more, or more appropriately, it won't work on your new button, but will continue to work on the default location.

Spotting still will not produce anything visible on the screen, only on the minimap as Bora pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

You are not doing anything wrong.

Spotting is turned off on hardcore. It only marks them on the minimap as red (hostile) dots.

Comment: Well it's not turned off completely... 3d spotting is turned off (ie you and other players don't see the orange triangles), but they do show up on the minimap.

And you do say stuff like "Enemy tank spotted", at least when on foot or in tank.